# Fredhopper qservers high response time issue

Tags: 2013-sp1, smarttarget, fredhopper

I have observed that our qservers (we have 2 of them) at times have high response time (60 seconds). This results in timeout exception which we observe in logs. Once i restart them, their response time get to about 70ms and everything works fine.

Is there something that I can do investigate why they get slow beside checking logs?

./bin/chk-up indexer will give me only response time, but not information WHY is response time so slow.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have checked fredhopper learning center (login required) and found couple of articles related to fredhopper monitoring and memory tuning:

Following fredhopper articles expain what proposed values for memory should be:
https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Fredhopper+Memory+Settings
https://www.fredhopper.com/learningcenter/display/learningcenter/Performance+Tuning+Fredhopper

Comment: Could you summarize the settings that worked for you, for the people who do not have a login to the Learning Center?

Comment: @Marko, when was the last time the fredhopper indices were rebuilt?

Comment: Hi @Philip, its good to hear from you. Its been about 2 months since we did reindex and push to live, but we haven't done rebuild of indices, so i think it was last done by you. Is there some recommendation in which intervals it should be done?